# Há uma maneira de imprimir tudo sem a quebra de linha?

Tags: python

Tenho este código:

```
print "t"
print "e"
print "s"
print "t"
print "e"
```

Ele tem como saída:

```
t
e
s
t
e
```

O que acho bem chato esses  `"\n"`.

Há uma maneira de imprimir tudo sem a quebra de linha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print 't' + 'e' + 's' + 't' + 'e'
```

O print por padrão sempre faz uma quebra de linha no fim, se você quiser, você pode escrever direto em sys.stdout que não vai ter quebra de linha

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('teste')
```

Agora a própria função print nos python mais novos >3.0 dá pra escolher o separador e o final na linha:
veja a documentação da função e os valores default:

```
print(...)
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

> Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default. Optional
>   keyword arguments: file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the
>   current sys.stdout. sep: string inserted between values, default a
>   space. end: string appended after the last value, default a newline.
>   flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.

você pode fazer no python3:

```
print('teste', end='', flush=True)
```

Answer (score 20):

Se estiver a usar python 3.x:

```
print('t', end="")
print('e', end="")
print('s', end="")
print('t', end="")
print('e')
```

Se não (se for python2.x) a maneira mais facil para não importar coisas desnecessárias seria mesmo incluir todos os caracteres na mesma string:

```
print 'teste' # python2.x
```

OU

```
print('teste') # python3.x
```

Imagino que isso possa estar a surgir de um ciclo a percorrer caracteres e está a fazer print logo dentro do ciclo, então em vez de fazer print logo dentro do ciclo porque não fazer assim:

```
str = 'teste'
final = ''
for i in str:
    final += i
print(final) # python 3.x
#print final #python 2
```

[RELACIONADO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240540/existe-alguma-forma-de-excluir-o-espa%C3%A7o-autom%C3%A1tico-que-aparece-depois-da-v%C3%ADrgula)

Comment: +1 boa resposta

Answer (score 8):

Na verdade, o contexto da pergunta parece que não é algo a ser muito utilizado no dia-a-dia de programação.

Não faz muito sentido você querer imprimir letra por letra com o `print`, se você pode fazer assim diretamente:

```
print "teste"
```

Há casos sim, onde você pode querer ter essa string separada em cada letra. Nesse caso você pode fazer

```
test = "teste"

list(test); # ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e']
```

No python 3, se precisasse imprimir todos os valores de um `list`, sem separação de linha por linha, você poderia fazer assim:

```
  print (*['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], sep="")

  #ou

  teste = list("teste");

  print(*test, sep="");

  #ou

  test = ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e']

  print(*test, sep="");
```

Answer (score 4):

Se estiveres a utilizar python 2.7 podes fazer o seguinte:

```
print "t",
print "e",
print "s",
print "t",
print "e"
```

Se também não quiseres o espaço entre caracteres:

```
import sys
print "t",
sys.stdout.write("")
print "e",
sys.stdout.write("")
print "s",
sys.stdout.write("")
print "t",
sys.stdout.write("")
print "e"
```

Caso estejas a utilizar python 3.5:

```
print("t", end="")
print("e", end="")
print("s", end="")
print("t", end="")
print("e", end="")
```

Answer (score 4):

Amigo, eu pensei em algo bem mais simples.
Criei uma Função para receber um parâmetro, e usá-lo com o print() e *end=""*:

```
def printf (text):
    print(text, end="")
```

E pronto, toda vez que quero escrever algo uso a função criada *printf()*
Por exemplo:

```
printf("Olá como")
printf("você está")
printf("hoje ?")
```

retorna:

```
Olá como você está hoje ?
```

Abraços.

Comment: Obrigado. Irei postar daqui a pouco uma pergunta sobre gráficos em Python. Posso deixar o link aqui?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217370/gr%c3%a1fico-em-python-n%c3%a3o-exibe-todos-os-valores-desejados

Answer (score 1):

Para isso basta por uma vírgula após o print
por exemplo:

```
`for item in "California":
  if item == "i":
    print "x",
  else:
    print item,`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(raw_input())
i=1
while(i<=n):
    print(i ,end="" )        
    i+=1
```