# Problema de quebra de linha

Tags: python

Meu código ta dando erro no uri de Presentation error, que é sobre quebra de linha

```
a = 0
p = [2,3,4,1]
s = str(input()).split(" ")
for k in range(4):
    a = a + float(s[k])*p[k]

a = a/(2+3+4+1)
print("Media: {:.1f}\n".format(a))
if a >= 7.0:
    print("Aluno aprovado.\n")
elif a >= 5.0:
    print("Aluno em exame.\n")
    ne = float(input())
    m = (ne+a)/2
    print("Nota do exame: {:.1f}\n".format(ne))
    if m >= 5:
        print("Aluno aprovado.\n")
    else:
        print("Aluno reprovado.\n")
    print("Media final: {:.1f}\n".format(m))
else:
    print("Aluno reprovado.\n")
```

Porém, não consigo achar um erro neste código...

Comment: Fato - ele executa normalmente aqui - pode dizer exatamente o que você está fazendo? (E colocar o erro também)

Comment: É um exercicio no Uri Online. O resultado está correto, mas o site retorna um error de "Presentation error", que é erros "visuais" (ou mal apresentados), geralmente são quebras de linhas que não foram colocados... Mas já tentei de todas as formas...

Comment: Mas já descobri... em python ele sempre pula uma linha dps do "print"...
eu estava pulando duas então...

Comment: Boa! [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146080/h%c3%a1-uma-maneira-de-imprimir-tudo-sem-a-quebra-de-linha/146083#146083) tem uma explicação de como fazer o `print` não quebrar linha.