# Gráfico em Python não exibe todos os valores desejados

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Gostaria que no gráfico aparecessem apenas os valores das coordenadas x, y correspondentes aos pontos. Mas não está assim:

[image: Gráfico incorreto]

Por exemplo:

O ponto cuja coordenada X é 04/10/2017 09:41:00 não exibe o valor da sua coordenada Y.

O ponto seguinte não exibe o valor da coordenada X.

O código em Python é o seguinte:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


x = []
y = []

dataset = open("/datasetDdos10Abril2017_unixtime_slowloris.csv","r")
##separacao no csv eh por virgulas


for line in dataset:
    line = line.strip() #23,24\n -> 23,24 retira a quebra de linha
    X,Y = line.split(",") #separador eh a virgula
    x.append( float(X))
    y.append(float (Y))

dataset.close()


x1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x]


plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

plt.plot(x1, y, 'ro')

plt.title("Número de Conexões por segundo: Ataque Sockstress")
plt.ylabel("Número de Conexões por segundo")
plt.xlabel('Tempo')

#plt.gca().set_ylim([0, 29800])
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

O arquivo datasetDdos10Abril2017_unixtime_slowloris.csv é assim:

```
1491828000 ,1959
1491828060 ,1652
1491828120 ,1673
1491828180,1610
1491828240,1620
1491828300,3252
1491828360,1617
1491828420 ,1658
1491828480 ,1605
1491828540 ,1615
1491828600 ,1613
1491828660 ,1626
1491828720 ,1640
1491828780 ,1638
1491828840 ,1625
1491828900 ,1580
1491828960 ,1618
1491829020 ,1608
1491829080 ,1619
1491829140 ,1628
1491829200 ,1626
1491829260 ,1640
1491829320 ,1639
1491829380 ,1631
1491829440 ,1635
1491829500 ,1646
1491829560 ,1633
1491829620 ,1599
1491829680 ,1660
1491829740 ,1655
1491829800 ,1647
1491829860 ,1646
1491829920 ,1651
1491829980 ,1625
1491830040 ,1546
1491830100 ,1580
1491830160 ,1614
1491830220,1631
1491830280 ,1618
1491830340 ,1633
```

Onde a primeira coluna são Unix times e a segunda coluna representa o número de conexões por segundo.

Como corrigir o gráfico de forma a exibir os valores das coordenadas de TODOS os pontos (x,y)

Comment: @Miguel: podes ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Solução para o eixo `x`:

`xticks` define a localização dos *ticks* e dos *labels* no eixo `x`, então basta passar `x1` para ele:

```
plt.xticks(x1)
```

> Solução para o eixo `y`:

Para o `y`, os números ficaram muito próximos e, portanto, ilegíveis - para eliminar alguns, como sugerido, podemos fazer assim:

```
y1 = []
v = 0
for i in sorted(y):
    if(abs(i-v > 50)): # 50 é a distância mínima entre cada número
        y1.append(i)
        v = i
```

E inserimos da mesma maneira:

```
plt.yticks(y1) # usamos yticks, porque agora é no eixo y
```

> Resultado:

[image: plot com posição correta sobre timestamp]

> Código completo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = []
y = []

dataset = open("./datasetDdos10Abril2017_unixtime_slowloris.csv","r")
##separacao no csv eh por virgulas

for line in dataset:
    line = line.strip() #23,24\n -> 23,24 retira a quebra de linha
    X,Y = line.split(",") #separador eh a virgula
    x.append( float(X))
    y.append(float (Y))

dataset.close()

x1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x]

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

y1 = []
v = 0
for i in sorted(y):
    if(abs(i-v > 50)):
        y1.append(i)
        v = i

plt.plot(x1, y, 'ro')

plt.title("Número de Conexões por segundo: Ataque Sockstress")
plt.ylabel("Número de Conexões por segundo")
plt.xlabel('Tempo')
plt.xticks(x1)
plt.yticks(y1)

#plt.gca().set_ylim([0, 29800])
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Obrigado! E o eixo y? fica estranho?

Comment: @EdS só ficaram uns em cima dos outros, por serem valores muito próximos... :(

Comment: tem como eu cortar alguns valores? Por exemplo, 5100 e 5200 nao tem pontos... Assim reduziriam os valores!!!!

Comment: @EdS editei para incluir uma possível solução, dê uma olhada!

Comment: :Teria como deixar as duas opções de resposta? Esta e a sua anterior?

Comment: @EdS sim! na verdade acredito que as duas estejam ali - de qualquer forma editei para tentar deixar mais claro - para modificar apenas o x, basta não utilizar o cógido da solução y, ou comentar a linha `plt.yticks(y1)`. (eu tinha escrito errado a chamada do yticks, corrigi isso também).

Comment: :modifiquei um pouco o dataset e o código não mais funciona. Teria com ajudar? Caso prefira, posso criar uma nova pergunta!

Comment: @EdS eu aconselho que você faça isso mesmo - acredito ser mais rápido de conseguir uma resposta! :)