# Existe alguma forma de excluir o espaço automático que aparece depois da vírgula em python?

Tags: python-3.x

Um breve exemplo:

```
zero = 0
print('exemplo',zero)
```

O programa mostra:

> exemplo 0

Eu queria sem o espaço:

> exemplo0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dessa forma exata, `print('exemplo',zero)`, não.

Mas a maneira (disponível só em python3.x) mais parecida com isso, em que o espaço é retirado é:

```
zero = 0
print('exemplo', zero, sep='') # exemplo0
```

[DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Aqui ficam outras maneiras de isso acontecer:

```
zero = 0
```

1. [Format](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3)

   ```
   print('exemplo{}'.format(zero))
   ```
2. Sinal de `+`

   ```
   print('exemplo' +str(zero)) # aqui, se ja for string escusas de usar str(...)
   ```
3. [%](https://pyformat.info/)

   ```
   print('exemplo%d' % zero)
   ```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/LdI1/1)

Também podes criar o teu próprio `print()` para coisas como esta:

```
def my_print(*args):
   print(*args, sep='')

zero = 0
my_print('example', zero, 1, 2, 'olá') # example012olá
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/LdPX/1)