# Leitura de arquivo sem exibir espaço

Tags: python

Galera, eu gostaria de saber como faço para imprimir um arquivo txt sem exibir a quebra de linhas e os espaços.

Exemplo, o texto no arquivo.txt é esse:

> O rato roeu a roupa
>   Do rei de Roma

Eu gostaria de imprimi-lo assim:

> Oratoroeuaroupadoreideroma

Sera que alguém poderia me dar um help? Vlw

Comment: pode usar o .replace(' ',''), isso vai tirar todos os espaços

Comment: Seja bem vindo heitor, isto te ajudaria? [Há uma maneira de imprimir tudo sem a quebra de linha?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146080/h%C3%A1-uma-maneira-de-imprimir-tudo-sem-a-quebra-de-linha)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para remover todos os caracteres especiais, [pode utilizar a função isalnum()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518/remove-all-special-characters-punctuation-and-spaces-from-string):

```
frase = "O rato roeu a roupa\n Do rei de Roma"
#Remove todos os caracteres especiais
frase = ''.join(e for e in frase if e.isalnum())
#Coloca tudo em minúsculo
frase = frase.lower()
#Coloca primeira letra maiúscula
frase = frase.capitalize()

print(frase)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Breno, funcionou perfeitamente aqui

Answer (score 2):

Também consegue fazer o que pretende com uma expressão regular. Talvez seja um pouco exagerado para o exemplo que tem, mas é sempre bom saber mais formas de chegar ao resultado final.

Para tal bastaria procurar com a expressão regular `\s`, que procura por qualquer *white space*, ou seja espaço, enter, tab, e depois substitui cada um desses carateres encontrados por uma string vazia:

```
import re
frase = "O rato roeu a roupa\n Do rei de Roma"
nova_frase = re.sub(r"\s", "", frase) # procura por \s e substitui por ""
print(nova_frase) # 'OratoroeuaroupaDoreideRoma'
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/m6DYdQ)